# not able to get custom field values using get_the_ID() in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i am trying to get the custom field value in wordpress using current post id but i am not able to get. What i am doing here is i have set the value of a custom field named 'woo_id' in which i have stored woo commerce's product id. I am using get_the_ID() function to get the id. I am new to woo commerce and wordpress. Below is the snippet of the code.

```
$custom_fields = get_post_custom(get_the_ID());
    $my_custom_field = $custom_fields['woo_id'];
    foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value ) {
        echo do_shortcode('[add_to_cart id='.$value.' sku=""]');
    }
```

Comment: Are you using this code inside the Loop?

Comment: @WaseemAbuSenjer yes

Comment: Please try to add this line at the end of this code and see what prints:

`print_r($my_custom_field);`

Comment: Plus, Are you sure that there is a value for the meta key 'woo_id' for the current post?

Comment: @WaseemAbuSenjer i dont get anything also when i tried to echo the get_the_ID() i got to see my id. but when i passed it as parameter i got nothing.

Comment: @WaseemAbuSenjer yes there is i tested it by passing custom value in the place of ID

Comment: Hmm, this is weird, try not to pass anything to get_post_custom (), it will take the current post ID by default.

Comment: @WaseemAbuSenjer solved it was opening up always the wrong page sorry for wasting ur time. My bad.